# How can I add a column that depends on another columns value, but also involves other rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As you can see, the TransactionNo's are not unique, in other words not every entry is its own order. So I want to make a column that have a list of all items for a particular TransactionNo when Coffee was bought with that TransactionNo.

For example, on row 7(TransactionNo 5) you see coffee is bought. So I want a column that called 'extras' that puts the other items bought with TransactionNo 5 on it. So under the column 'extras', on row 7, you would see a list ['Pastry', 'Bread']. I've tried using `np.where` but I cannot figure this out.

```
TransactionNo   Items
0   1   Bread
1   2   Scandinavian
2   2   Scandinavian
3   3   Hot chocolate
4   3   Jam
5   3   Cookies
6   4   Muffin
7   5   Coffee
8   5   Pastry
9   5   Bread
```

I tried `df['extras'] = np.where(df['Items'] == 'Coffee', x, y)` but couldn't figure out what to put for x or y.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the items except `Coffee` into list then assign the list to the `Coffee`

```py
m = df['Items'].eq('Coffee')

dct = df.loc[~m, 'Items'].groupby(df['TransactionNo']).agg(list)

df['extras'] = df['TransactionNo'].map(dct).where(m, '')
```

```
$ print(dct)

TransactionNo
1                          [Bread]
2     [Scandinavian, Scandinavian]
3    [Hot chocolate, Jam, Cookies]
4                         [Muffin]
5                  [Pastry, Bread]
Name: Items, dtype: object

$ print(df)

   TransactionNo          Items           extras
0              1          Bread
1              2   Scandinavian
2              2   Scandinavian
3              3  Hot chocolate
4              3            Jam
5              3        Cookies
6              4         Muffin
7              5         Coffee  [Pastry, Bread]
8              5         Pastry
9              5          Bread
```